# Using parameter values for schema and table in Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to use a query where the **schema** and **table** are passed as parameters into a **prepared statement** using **pg_query_params** like this:

```
$searchSchema = 'mySchema';
$searchTable = 'myTable';
$searchColumn = 'searchColumn';
$searchValue = 'some value';

$selQuery = "SELECT *

FROM $1.$2  --fails here

WHERE someColumn like $3;";

$rs = pg_query_params($db, $selQuery , array($searchSchema, $searchTable, $searchColumn, $searchValue));
```

The issue is with the schema and table which need to be set dynamically - as in the code above.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe please could you remove the 'marked as duplicate' please?

Comment: Sure, if you can explain what is different...

Comment: In essence, you have to compose the query as a string. You cannot use parameters for table or column names.

Comment: This is a different question from the one shown as duplicate. The other question is about the column names which I am not concerned about. My question is about passing the schema and table to the query. Also, I am using pg_query_params which has a different structure to the example in the other question.

Comment: In essence it is the same thing. You can neither use table names nor column names as parameters to a prepared statement, neither with pg_query_params or otherwise. PostgreSQL does not allow it, there is nothing PHP can do about it.

Comment: @Laurenz Thanks for the answer. That's a good explanation that could have been posted as an answer. So, should it still be marked as duplicate? - If so I'll delete the question which would be a shame as there is some information that would be helpful to others.

Comment: Ok, ok. I thought you would be satisfied with being pointed towards the solution, but I'm happy to write up an answer if that is better for you.

Comment: @Laurenz thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a parameterized SQL statement (which is a *prepared statement* in PostgreSQL), parameters can only stand for constant values, not for table or column names.

This limitation is enforced by PostgreSQL, and there is no way around it, no matter what programming language or driver you use. This is also intentional and not a bug.

You will have to compose a string that contains the complete SQL statement with table and column names substituted and execute that. Beware of SQL injection – use functions like [`pg_escape_identifier`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-identifier.php) to escape names.